# fusing two different baud rates in arduino

Tags: arduino, gps, atmega

I am using `UBLOX-GPS` with Baud rate of `9600` and `IMU Razor`with Baud rate of `57600` to `Arduino MEGA`. Now how I can call the data for same sample rate?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about "fusing" doesn't make much sense, but your Arduino Mega has 4 UARTs (which means it has four hardware serial ports, each of which may be configured and used independently), so you can simply connect the GPS to one and the IMU to another. I'd suggest using Serial1 and Serial2, because Serial0 (pins 0 and 1) is connected to the USB-TTL converter.